# Why do we pass self when calling the constructor of super class?

Tags: python, class, oop, constructor

In the code below the i have called the constructor of class A in class B but I need to pass self in the parameters.
Why do we to pass self that is a reference to object B to the constructor of A?
Using Python 3.7.3

```
class A:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.a = a
    def get_a(self):
        print(self.a)
class B(A): 
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        A.__init__(self,a)
        self.b = b
    def get_b(self):
        print(self.a)
        print(self.b)

a = A(5)
b = B(50,60)
a.get_a()
b.get_a()
b.get_b()
```

Comment: Because that's the method signature?

Comment: Note that the instance of B is also an instance of A - that's OOP.

Comment: You need an instance of class A to avoid passing self by yourself, if you want to call a method from parent class you should use super https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super

Comment: `__init__()` is _not_ a constructor (like C++ classes have), it's a class instance initializer and needs to be able to refer to the instance in order to be able to set-up its state.